# After creating entry in gorm , Fetch operations fails

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlite, go, go-gorm

We have a scenario where we are create an entry in postgres table using gorm with below snippet

```
func (r *Repository) CreateUser(ctx context.Context, user *model.User) error {
       return r.db.WithContext(ctx).Create(&user).Error
}
```

User table has primary key as UUID which will be generated before entry creation in table . Above statement does not return any error instead we are getting UUID in return .

When i am using Fetch using same UUID in golang , I am facing record not found error . This issue seems to be an intermittent issue . Sometime it works and sometime it does not . We have validated the queries and everything seems to be correct.

Below is the snippet where we are getting user with roll_id

```
func (r *Repository) FetchUserByRollId(ctx context.Context, id string) (*model.User, error) {
    var user *model.User
    err := r.db.WithContext(ctx).Scopes(userRollIdScope(id)).First(&user).Error
    if err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
    return user, err
}
```

Scope as below:

```
func userRollIdScope(id string) func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Where(&model.User{RollId: id})
    }
}
```

Even after creation , fetch fails . What could be the issue here.
Tried Below way also just to be confirm that whether entry is commited or not but still facing same issue

```
func (r *Repository) CreateUser(ctx context.Context, user *model.User) error {
    tx := r.db.WithContext(ctx).Begin()
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
        }
    }()
    // Perform database operation within the transaction
    if err := tx.Create(&user).Error; err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }
    // Commit the transaction if there are no errors
    if err := tx.Commit().Error; err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Versions used**
GORM version: `v1.25.1`
Postgres driver Version: `v1.5.2`

Any suggestions?

Fetch query should return correct entry

Comment: `FetchUserByRollId` swallows errors unless it is a `gorm.ErrRecordNotFound`  and will return a nil user and an error  in case it failed to retrieve the user for any reason. The whole error handling, as set up, is redundant, since no additional information is added: if err is not nil, user will still be nil. All that happens in the  `errors.Is` clause is to return nil and a the error - which you also do with `return user, err` in case there was an error. Improve the error handling, the problem will most likely be reported back to you.